# How to check if a document is empty in Firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following `DocumentReference`:

```js
const risultati = await firestore.collection("Risultati").doc("risultati").get();
```

This document always exists but sometimes has 0 fields.
I'd like to check if the document is empty (no fields in it).
I'm trying this code:
`risultati.data().length`
returning `undefined`

Screenshot of document:[image]

**EDIT with further informations**:

The function that deletes document's fields is the following:

```js
exports.delete = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('55 3 * * *')
  .onRun(async (context) => {
  const risultati = await firestore.collection("Risultati").doc("risultati").get();
  for(id in risultati.data()){
    if(risultati.data()[id]!=0){
      await firestore.collection("Risultati").doc("risultati").update({
        [id]: fieldValue.delete()
      });

    }

  }



  return null;

});
```

The output of `console.log(risultati.data())` is blank, as indicates the line following "function execution started".
[image]

Comment: Can you please explain _"This document always exists but sometimes has 0 fields."_ and also share a screenshot of that document?

Comment: @Dharmaraj added a screenshot of the document when it is empty. The document isn't always empty, sometimes there are some fields written and then they are deleted (not in the same time, so I can't delete the entire document and use `document.data().exists`. I'd like to check if the document is empty or not

Comment: Does `risultati.exists` work? I though the document might have a sub collection as it's shown but is empty but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: no, it doesn't work because `risultati` exists even if it is empty

Comment: Can you please tell how did you get empty document without a sub-collection? (and does that disappear from the console if you refresh it)? Also what does `console.log(risultati.data())` output? Can you share its screenshot as well? I was not able to recreate the same issue.

Comment: It's still unclear why would that happen, but as all the keys are present in  a single document, you can delete all nodes in a single operation that'll only cost you 1 write operation.

Comment: I however need to check the condition on every key. Yes, I could use `batchwrite` to use only 1 write operation, but the document is very small so it isn't very impactful. Thank you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a document with some fields and delete those fields, that's how you can end up with an empty document.
As such, Firestore does not provide a function which can check if document is empty or not, but you can check it yourself.

```
if(Object.entries(doc.data()).length < 1){
      // your document is empty
}
```